# Where to add events to buttons with typescript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, typescript

Where do I add events to buttons, input fields etc? I ask because I want to hold as much JS/jQuery away from my view. Right now this is what I do:

I have my view:

```html
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Application/Currency/CurrencyExchangeRateCreate.js?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString())

<script>
    var x = new CurrencyExchangeRateCreate();
    var createUrl = @Url.Action("Create", "Currency"),
        indexUrl = @Url.Action("Index", "Currency");
</script>
```

And my typescript class

```
var createUrl, indexUrl;
class CurrencyExchangeRateCreate {
    private form: JQuery = $("#createForm");
    private submitButton: JQuery = $("#submitButton"); 

    constructor() {
        var self = this;
        this.submitButton.on("click", function () {
            self.Create();
        })
    }

    public Create() {
        var self = this;
        var ajaxOptions: JQueryAjaxSettings = {
            async: true,
            url: createUrl,
            data: self.form.serialize(),
            method: "POST",
            global: true,
            success: function () {
                window.location.href = indexUrl;
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        }    
        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    }    
}
```

Like you can see I have a form which I can submit on click of a button, but this button click event must be bound somewhere. If I do it in the constructor then I have to instantiate the new class as I did right now. Is it the right way to do this, or are there any better ways?

Comment: why do you want to do this in class. IMHO this should be done after `DOMContentLoaded/.ready` event has been fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class CurrencyExchangeRateCreate {
    // all the class properties and methods without any event binding.

    private form: JQuery = $("#createForm");
    private submitButton: JQuery = $("#submitButton");

    // a suggestion for the constructor:
    constructor(createUrl, indexUrl) {
      this.createUrl = createUrl;
      this.indexUrl  = indexUrl;
    }

    // some changes in create method:

    public Create() {
        var self = this;
        var ajaxOptions: JQueryAjaxSettings = {
            async: true,
            url: this.createUrl,
            data: form.serialize(), //<----remove self from here.
            method: "POST",
            global: true,
            success: function () {
                window.location.href = this.indexUrl;
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        }    
        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    } 

}


var button = document.querySelector('#submitButton');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission.
    var createUrl = @Url.Action("Create", "Currency"),
        indexUrl  = @Url.Action("Index", "Currency");

    var x         = new CurrencyExchangeRateCreate(createUrl, indexUrl);
        x.Create(); // call the create method here.
});
```